# sql trying to change "select" statement result by replacing the value of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got this table :

| Id | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | bp sd mm |
| 2 | sm c ivc |

and I'm tying to change pb to Business Partner and sd to sales and distribution so on.
I did try this code:

```
select Id,          
,case 
when s.saptype = 'bp' then 'Business Partner'
when s.saptype = 'sd' then 'sales and distribution' 
end Type

from sap s
join mega b on s.BUID =b.BUID
left join  sector ss on ss.id= s.id
where b.Level > 1 and isnull(s.Inactive,0) =0
```

but I'm getting the following error:

> Msg 8621, Level 17, State 1, Line 1 The query processor ran out of stack space during query >>optimization. Please simplify the query.

**Note** that I did used **60** when then in this **Case** and there are **60** variety of Type column example **bp sd mm** and **mm pb sd** but only **10 acronym**, I know I can make a temp table and use left join but i want to know if there is any other way to do it.

Comment: How `saptype` in the query is related to `Type` in the table?

Comment: @Serg TY I did edit it just not but that's an example both table and the query.

Comment: What would your results look like? Do you want all three phrases in the same column, just like all abbreviations are currently in the same column? What do you want to separate the phrases by? Space would be bad, since your phrases already include spaces. Notice that your question indicates the problem with the design: You have multiple values associated with an `id` all in a single column. This is a many-to-one relationship. Had your multiple values each been in a different row, the query would be far simpler.

Comment: If I were to tackle this the first task would be to produce the *rows* that should exist to represent the data; the rows can then be joined to a mapping table for the appropriate substitutions, then re-aggregated as necessary. Sample data and desired results as per [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help here.

Comment: @allmhuran ,@Stu I used nested `REPLACE` and it does work just like i want ty every one

Comment: `The query processor ran out of stack space` is a very unusual error: it indicates perhaps exceedingly complex joins. Are any of these tables partitioned, or are they actually complex views? Side note: you probably want to move the filter on `Inactive` into the `ON` clause: `AND s.Inactive = 0`